# Emacs mouse support over terminal ssh

Tags: emacs

In my .vimrc file, I have this line:

```
set mouse=a
```

This enables the mouse to work with vim. You can move the point around by clicking, and it responds to the scroll wheel. It also works fine even in a vim instance accessed over a standard terminal emulator using SSH. Is there a way to enable the same functionality in Emacs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does xterm-mouse-mode do what you want?  I found it by searching "emacs 'set mouse=a'"